# How to link Firebase and GCP projects together?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We've recently created a GCP project and a Cloud Storage bucket in it.

Then we decided to use Firebase to host our React app. However, after creating the Firebase project (Why did we need to create a new project?), we got a different storage bucket. And it seems that it's not possible to view the same bucket from both projects.

Our backend uses a Cloud Storage bucket. Our frontend sends files to a Firestore bucket, which is different. How can we link it together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to know that a Firebase project **IS** a Google Cloud project.  Read more about that in this [blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/whats-the-relationship-between-firebase-and-google-cloud-57e268a7ff6f).  Firebase is essentially a layer of APIs and services in a Google Cloud project.  What you probably should have done in the first place is add Firebase to your existing Cloud project, but it's probably not worthwhile to do that if you already have an existing Firebase project.

There's really no way to link the projects together that would be convenient for you.  What I recommend you do is abandon your first Cloud project, and copy the contents of your first bucket into your Firebase project default bucket.  Also read more about the relationship between Firebase and Google Cloud with respect to Cloud Storage in this [blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-storage-a33fad7c2b80).

Comment: Thank you, I read the guide. We created a Firebase project on top of GCP project. It seems that now all the buckets are visible. I'm assuming what you meant in the 2nd paragraph is abandon the Firebase project, and create new Firebase project as addition to GCP project. (Our GCP project is much heavier in terms of deployments).

Comment: You actually chose the opposite of what I recommended.  It doesn't really matter - whatever works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase storage's `getStorage` function to specify the Google Cloud Storage Bucket. Then use gsutil to add the appropriate permissions between your Firebase project and the GCS bucket. You may need to edit the bucket permissions by going to `Storage > Buckets` and selecting `Edit Bucket Permissions` from the kebab menu (⋮) right of the bucket name. Here, you add can add the service-@gcp-sa-firebasestorage.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Frontend/browser Firebase code:

```
import { getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseApp = getApp();
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp, "gs://my-custom-bucket");
```

command line to add permissions:

```
gsutil -m acl ch -r -u service-<project number>@gcp-sa-firebasestorage.iam.gserviceaccount.com gs://<my-custom-bucket>
```

The service-project number can be found in the Firebase project's console, under settings.